# Build Android Eclipse Project from SVN repository?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

Running Eclipse 3.8 with SVN plugin. I get to the point where I'm asked "Choose how to check out folder 'trunk'" and what seems right is to choose "Check out the project with the name specified:" and then it proceeds to check out all the code. It all seems fine but now I can't build anything. Build All/Build Project is grayed out with or without Build Automatically checked. So what are the next steps do get this thing recognized as a project,compiled and running? Thx.